# Suspending a Travis build

Tags: travis-ci

I have a `travis.yml` script as part of a package on my github site. So every time I push an update, it is automatically rebuilt and checked. However, sometimes I *know* it won't build correctly and I am just pushing my changes to keep from losing them.

Another incentive for suspending a build is that I literally cringe when I receive an e-mail with a subject line saying it has "errored." I wish somebody would tell this Travis guy that "error" is a noun, not a verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle your travis build would be to setup a branch where the build is trigger and to build in another branch. This way, you will do what you want and only trigger the build when you will do a merge.

About the verb errored, it isn't currently a verb. But it will maybe be, like to google. 
    error (third-person singular simple present errors, present participle     erroring, simple past and past participle errored)

```
(computing) To function improperly due to an error, especially accompanied by error message.

    The web-page took a long time to load and errored out.
    Remove that line of code and the script should stop erroring there.
    This directory errors with a "Permission denied" message.
```

Comment: Thanks. You're right; I need to get more sophisticated and do the development work on a different branch. I'm an old dog and new tricks are hard for me to learn. But in your "errored" examples... cringe ... cringe ... cringe (probably another aspect of being an old dog).

Comment: it's the same for me, errored always sound weird, but being a non native english speaker help a lot in this case !